# javascript passing a function object to a web worker - ERROR DataCloneError could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I need to use a web worker to open a separate thread an do some heavy CPU task.

I would need to task the web worker with a function call and arguments and then get the return, so I went for:

**funcs.js**

```
export default function add(args) {
  return args[0] + args[1];
}
```

**main.js**

```
import add from './funcs.js';
// [...]
this.worker.postMessage({func: add, args: [7, 3]});
```

then runtime error:

> `DataCloneError`: Failed to execute `postMessage` on `Worker`: `function add(args) {
>     return args[0] + args[1];
>   }`
>   could not be cloned.

It seems the `worker.postMessage` method only allow string to be passed,
any idea how I can work this around simply and elegantly?

Answer (score 5):

## About postMessage

[postMessage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) give a clear definition about what can or cannot be send to a worker:

> postMessage accept only value or JavaScript object handled by the structured clone algorithm, which includes cyclical references.

Looking at [the structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), it accept :

> **All primitive type**s *(However, not symbols)*, **Boolean** object, **String** object, **Date**, **RegExp** *(The lastIndex field is not preserved.)*, **Blob**, **File**, **FileList**, **ArrayBuffer**, **ArrayBufferView** *(This basically means all typed arrays like Int32Array etc.)*, **ImageBitmap**, **ImageData**, **Array**, **Object** *(This just includes plain objects (e.g. from object literals))*, **Map**, **Set**

But unfortunately :

> **Error** and **Function** objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.

So function is definitely not an option. A simple solution would be to import `add` directly in your worker.js file, and replace func by a string.

## Javascript

```
this.worker.postMessage( {func: 'ADD', args:[7, 3]} );
```

## worker.js

```
import add from './funcs.js';

onmessage = function(event) {
    const action = event.data;
    switch (action.func) {
        case 'ADD': {
            postMessage({
                result: add(action.args)
            });
        }
        break;
        ....
```

Comment: yes that would work, still i want the worker to exec func() generic, here i need to make an ugly switch/case with advance knowledge of the functions i will use, that's not as elegant as i think it could be, but thanks anyway that's a first step :-)

Comment: No, even though you can't pass functions, you can still pass a lot more data-types than strings: Plain objects can be cloned, (normally even cyclic ones, even though Chrome's implementation may fail in some cases), you can pass Blobs, you can transfer ArrayBuffers, ImageBitmap MessagePorts etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kaiido , learned something new today and corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot @sebastienbarbier (and @kaiido) that's getting more more clear and precise on how to... what to do...
Seems it's clonable object only, that's indeed key to make it work or throw error, if anyone knows an alternative...

Comment: You're welcome @uzer44713543. Please feel free to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it is a valid answer for others. "Accepting an answer is important as it rewards posters for correctly answering your question, informs others that your issue is resolved, and pins the answer to the top so others reading your question read that answer first."

Answer (score 0):

Well there I a way to call the function using eval, but you should be very careful when you use it.

For example:

main.js

```js
import add from './funcs.js';
// [...]
this.worker.postMessage({func: `${add}`, args: [7, 3]});
```

worker.js

```js
onmessage = function(event) {
    eval(event.func)(...event.args);
}
```

The important thing - you should avoid using anything out of function scope in the function.